# Download multiple extensions file from remote using JSCH

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I have remote directory `/remote/Dir` which have many files with different extensions.

like

```
     *.abc
     *.xyz
     *.pqr
```

I want to dowload all files ended with `.abc`  `.xyz`  `.pqr`

so in this case How I use JSCh?

Answer (score 2):

Add all the ls results in a vector.

```
Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = channelSftp.ls("*.abc");
list.addAll(channelSftp.ls("*.xyz"));
list.addAll(channelSftp.ls("*.pqr"));
```

After you need to execute a for loop on this list to gett all the matching files..

Comment: I have property file which have all this extensions like value="*.abc,*.xyz,*.pqr" so how would I get all extension one by one and add in Vector?

Comment: This solution requires a round trip to the server for each `ls()` operation, which is inefficient. It'd be more efficient to fetch a list of all files in the remote directory and filter them once locally. Unfortunately, this would require you to implement your own wildcard matching, because Jsch doesn't expose its wildcard logic.